# MethodInvoker vs new MethodInvoker

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, delegates

I am maintaining voip multithreaded windows form application and i can understand that MethodInvoker is used when we don't want to define delegate but want to use delegate to route data from worker thread to gui thread so this code make sense

```
 void Synch_ProgressComplete(bool Success)
    {
        _SynchPseudoGauge = 100;

        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)
                (() => { SynchProgressBar.Value = _SynchPseudoGauge; }));
        else
            SynchProgressBar.Value = _SynchPseudoGauge;

        _LastSynchAvailability = _Synch.Available;

        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)
                (() => { WebserviceAvailibilityLabel.ForeColor = Success ? Color.Black : Color.Red; }));
        else
            WebserviceAvailibilityLabel.ForeColor = Success ? Color.Black : Color.Red;


        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)
                (() => { WebserviceAvailibilityLabel.Text = Success ? "Webservice Available" : "Webservice Error"; }));
        else
            WebserviceAvailibilityLabel.Text = Success ? "Webservice Available" : "Webservice Error";
```

but i don't understand this bit

```
  SynchroniseDelegate SynchDelegate = new SynchroniseDelegate(_Synch.Synchronise);
                AsyncCallback SynchCallback = new AsyncCallback(Synch_Callback);
AsyncCallback SynchCallback = new AsyncCallback(Synch_Callback);
   SynchDelegate.BeginInvoke(Synchronisation.ForceSync.All, SynchCallback, new object() { });

private void Synch_Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(InitialiseTelephony), new object() { });
        }
```

can any one help please

Comment: What about it don't you understand?

Comment: What is the thing that you do not understand? The snippets that you *do* understand don't seem to be different from the one you do not understand.

Comment: why new operator is used with MethodInvoker while in the above code MethodInvoker is used without new operator

Comment: @Servy why new operator is used with MethodInvoker while in the above  code MethodInvoker is used without new operator

Comment: The Control.BeginInvoke() and a delegate's BeginInvoke() method are *completely* unrelated and do very different things.  Some background in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18019496/17034).

Comment: thanks for help. if  BeginInvoke is used and  EndInvoke is not called would it cause issues or not

Comment: @HansPassant. Thank you very much for post link. In my case delegate.BeginInvoke is used but no EndInvoke so do you think it should have EndInvoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code snippets above the author wants to create a delegate given a lambda expression. Lambda expressions do not have a CLR type (they do not have a delegate type). They are convertible to delegates, though.

In one case a lambda is converted to a delegate type. In the other case constructor syntax is being used to perform the conversion. The two variants do the same thing. You can do whatever you like.

Answer (score 2):

Casting a method to a delegate type, as is done in the first example, is functionally identical to the constructor-like syntax used in the second example.